# "Se revirtió la votación en serie"

Tags: discusión, soporte, reputación

Buen día, tarde y noche a todos los miembros de esta comunidad, el día de hoy expongo una pregunta, el día de hoy recibí varios mensajes que indican **"Se revirtió la votación en Serie"**. Me llamo la atención e imagino la razón por la que se realiza, seguramente para evitar puntos obtenidos fraudulentamente.

Mi pregunta es ¿cuales son los criterios que se toman para deducir se realizo una votación en serie? por ejemplo ¿Puede ser una o varias personas? o 
¿El tiempo el cual transcurrió la asignación de votos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!.

Comment: Probablemente tenías un fan y el sistema lo detectó. La fórmula para calcularlo creo que no podrás obtenerla ya que por comentarios anteriores he leido que se mantiene secreta para evitar que se divulge. Siendo el usuario de mayor reputación del sitio creo que eso te ocurrirá a menudo ;)