# Voto negativo de manera serial en mi perfil

Tags: soporte, reputación, voto-serial

Recién empieza el día para mi en México y recibo en menos de 5 minutos 34 votos negativos, esto me parece una conducta claramente troll y peligrosa

Comprendo que las respuestas pueden eventualmente con la opinión de otros usuarios recibir votos negativos, pero 34 votos en menos de 5 minutos me parece que no tiene intención de contribuir sino solo de dañar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede hacer algo al respecto?

Actualización

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no me preocuparía. El sistema detecta ese tipo de votos seriales y suele revertirlos.

Comment: Buenas! Como menciona @Pikoh esto es un tipo de voto serial y seguramente el sistema lo recoja. De momento no sale pero por seguro me pondré en contacto con el usuario que haya hecho el voto serial para hablar con él. Un saludo

Comment: Empatizo completamente con la sensación, shadow. Esperemos que se reviertan en las próximas horas. Si me apuras, es más doloroso recibir un voto negativo aquí y allá sin saber el motivo (de esos que te dejan pensando si la respuesta estará bien) que muchos de golpe: es claramente alguien enfadado y algo patoso. Mañana veás un +XX en la reputación y ya está.

Comment: hola @fedorqui saludos y gracias por el apoyo mostrado, si esto mas que pelea por los puntos, es por no saber el por que, ante todo agradezco en mi estancia aqui en SO en español para quien me ha votado negativo y me ha explicado pues de ahí aprendí y mejoré

Comment: @shadow exacto, yo lo mismo. De allí que este sea algún usuario que te votó por algo ajeno a tus publicaciones y probablemente tenga que ver con que le cerraras alguna pregunta o le comentaras algo que no le cayó en gracia. Sea como fuere, votó por algo ajeno al contenido y por tanto es un voto que debe ser invalidado.

Comment: @fedorqui solo para comentarte que efectivamente ya se revirtió la votación, gracias no solo por las palabras sino por la orientación

Comment: Cuando te vuelva a pasar, avisame y revisaré tu perfil. ahora he mirado pero aun no sale. el script que analiza los votos actua más tarde. Pero no te preocupes que el usuario anterior ya ha sido contactado y este lo será. y los votos se retractan. Un saludo

Comment: gracias @lois6b un saludo, creo que hice enojar a mas de uno jejeje

Comment: Bienvenido al club Shadow @element https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/960/se-revirti%C3%B3-la-votaci%C3%B3n-en-serie  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404/se-puede-realizar-algo-contra-el-voto-serial-negativo , **es importante comentar que también implica "votación serial" al votar positivamente a un usuario**.

Comment: @Elenasys si, yo tuve 4 usuarios que hicieron votos seriales que eran upvotes... tanta reputacion y al dia siguiente perdida... aish

Comment: jajajaja me sentiré afortunado aunque después la pierda, el día que me pase lo mismo que a ustedes @lois6b

Comment: A mí una vez me quitaron vaaaarios cientos de puntos, supuestamente por algo así.

Comment: @Shaz eso parecería incluso un ataque coordinado